# Find the domain of a cos inverse function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given function:
$y = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\{x\}}\right)$

where $\{x\}$ is [fractional part function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part).

I need to find the domain for this function, but how do I solve the inequality I get for $\frac{1}{\{x\}}$?. I am getting $-1\leq{\{x\}}\leq1$, but how do I proceed after that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\{x\}$ fractional part of $x$, $$\therefore\{x\}\in[0,1)\implies\frac{1}{\{x\}}>1 \quad{\text{for all real values of $x$}}$$

Now, $\cos^{-1}$ or $\arccos$ function is defined for value in $[-1,1]$. Clearly, there is no $x$ possible to define,$$y = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\{x\}}\right)$$

Hence, domain of the $y$ is $\phi$ set.